# Changing data type from decimal to Int In SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

In a table Id column has been set as decimal(10,0) previously. I can see this is useless and I would like to change it into int type.

However table contains some data and I would like to keep the data. The Id is a primary key and been referenced by other tables. It is also worth mentioning that the column is auto-increment.

I wonder whether it would be possible to alter decimal into int without affecting the existing data in the table?

Comment: you can alter table with affecting any data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first drop your all the foreign key constraint  referencing this Table Then drop `Primary key constraint` then alter column with `datatype int` Then add `Primary key` once again.

**For Every Referenced Table Execute this Line**

```
 1. ALTER TABLE foreignkeytableName DROP FOREIGN KEY constraintName;
     ALTER TABLE foreignkeytableName ALTER Column RefColumnName Int ;
```

**For Primary Table**

```
  1. ALTER TABLE TableName  drop constraint Primary key Constraint Name

     2. ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER Column ID Int 

     3. ALTER TABLE TableName ADD  Primary key (ID)
```

**Add Foreign key for Every Referenced Table**

```
ALTER TABLE foreignkeytableName ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraitName 
FOREIGN KEY (Fk_ColumnName) REFERENCES PrimaryKeyTableName(PK_ColumnName)
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to drop `PRIMARY KEY` constraint then alter your column to int and then crete `PRIMARY KEY` again for this column something like this:

```
alter table Table
drop constraint constraint_name

alter table Table
alter column column_name int not null

alter table Table
add constraint constraint_name primary key (column_name)
```